# Why is this stack variable in C not in a register?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, buffer-overflow, register-allocation

I have a reasonable understanding of how to execute buffer overflow attacks and how register allocation works in compilers.

What confuses me is why so many things are on the stack in C programs.
Consider this vulnerable program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    char str[] = "ABC";
    gets(str);
    printf("int: %d, str: %s\n", a, str);
    return a;
}
```

Let's run it

```sh
> gcc run.c
> ./a.out asdfasdf
int: 1717859169, str: asdfasdf
```

Okay so str is overwritten as is `int a`. But why is `int a` even on the stack?
Wouldn't it be easiest to just do something like (x86 asm)

```
.global _main
.text
_main:
        // omitting the gets() stuff
        movq $0, %rax
        retq
```

Now we have less memory traffic since nothing is on the stack and much less code.

tl;dr why is `int a` on the stack at all?

Comment: `Wouldn't it be easiest to just do something like (x86 asm)` Yes, it would be possible to __optimize__ the code. But you compile without optimizations.

Comment: TL;DR: Did you compile with optimizations on or not? `-O3` or forget about making any sense of it.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense I'm looking at the optimized assembly right now and it does not exhibit the same overflow behavior. The code above is what I ran no -O3.

Comment: When I compile it with `-O3`, it doesn't even store `a` in a register. The optimizer knows that it's always `0`, so it uses `xor eax, eax` whenever it needs to refer to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments on my post.
It happens because I am compiling without optimization and when I compile with optimizations `gcc -O3 run.c` I won't see the same behavior.

Here's some of the optimized assembly

```
> gcc -o run -O3 run.c
> objdump -d run

...
// Set eax = 0
100003f5c: 31 c0                        xorl    %eax, %eax  
100003f5e: 48 83 c4 08                  addq    $8, %rsp
100003f62: 5b                           popq    %rbx
100003f63: 5d                           popq    %rbp
// Return 0
100003f64: c3                           retq
```

And the more complicated unoptimized:

```
...
// put 0 on the stack
100003f33: c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00         movl    $0, -8(%rbp) the stack
...
// take it off the stack and into ecx
100003f61: 8b 4d f8                     movl    -8(%rbp), %ecx 
100003f64: 89 45 e4                     movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)
100003f67: 89 c8                        movl    %ecx, %eax
100003f69: 48 83 c4 20                  addq    $32, %rsp
100003f6d: 5d                           popq    %rbp
// return 0
100003f6e: c3                           retq
```